# AES Decryption counter mode

Tags: python, aes, pycrypto

I have a 64 character string. The first 32 characters are represent the IV and the last 32 characters are the encrypted message. Each character represents 4 bits, so I have to interpret the string in pairs to get a single byte.

What I am trying to do is to replicate how counter-mode decryption works. As I understand the process, I should be able to xor my cipher text against the encryption of my IV and this should yield the plain text. (note that my cipher text = 16 bytes = one block, so no padding or incrementing of the IV is necessary here, I believe.)

No matter how I do this, I don't get anything legible to output. I think that my problem is how I am encrypting my IV, but I don't know for sure. I've been attacking this forever, but I'm getting nowhere. Can anyone see what I am doing wrong? Here's the code that I wrote:

```
def decryptCTR(key, ciphertext):
    IV = ciphertext[:32]
    C0 = ciphertext[32:64]
    #convert into 16 byte strings
    key = array.array('B', key.decode("hex")).tostring()
    IV = array.array('B', IV.decode("hex")).tostring()

    # ENCRYPT iv with the key
    encodeAES = lambda c, s: base64.b64encode(c.encrypt(s))
    cipher = AES.new(key, AES.MODE_CFB)
    encryptedIV = encodeAES(cipher, IV)

    #xor the encrypted iv with the ciphertext block
    print "XOR: " + strXOR(encryptedIV, C0)

    return
```

Comment: you could use `key = binascii.unhexlify(key)`. In your code `strXOR()` receives one argument as a base64 encoded string and another as a hex string. It doesn't seem right. Does it work `cypher=AES.new(key16, CFB, iv16); cypher.decrypt(unhexlify(c0))`?

Comment: http://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc3686 rfc 3686 contains a good description of what is necessary and test vectors.

Comment: Thanks to both of you. I didn't even know about the unhexlify command, but it seems to wind up with the same result as my array.array...tostring() operation. I didn't show the function strXOR(), since it is outside of what I am dealing with here, but it works just fine.  Still making no progress...

Comment: i suspect this won't help, but since there's no marked correct answer here you may be desperate enough to work through it.  the code at https://github.com/andrewcooke/particl/blob/master/src/cl/parti/random.clj uses aes in ctr mode to generate a stream of random data.  *however*, although it calls java crypto classes, it's written in clojure.  one thing i notice checking my code against yours is that you don't need to xor.  that's done for you by the encrypt routines.    the tests at https://github.com/andrewcooke/particl/blob/master/test/cl/parti/random-test.clj check against the rfc above.

Answer (score 2):

The answer is indeed simple: don't encrypt the IV. The IV should be send in the clear.

Comment: Yes, the IV is sent in the clear. However, in order to encrypt a block of plaintext, you have to encrypt the IV using they key and then xor this encrypted IV with the plaintext. That's what I am trying to do here, to no avail. Thanks for the suggestion, though.

Comment: OK, I see what you are trying to do. I don't see how you know it is right or wrong though, and how your counter works.